# Normalized MySQL Pivot / Rows to Columns without unique names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot-table

I've seem to hit a wall trying to figure out an appropriate query for the following database (simplified):

#### 'Users' Table

```
userID    userName
1         John
2         Jane
```

#### 'Ingredients' Table

*NOTE: This table will get fairly large!*

```
ingredientID     ingredientName     ingredientImage
1                Tomatoes           tomato.png
2                Onions             onion.png
3                Red Pepper         redPepper.png
```

#### 'Recipes' Table

```
recipeID     userID     recipeName     description
1            1          Tomato Sauce   My homemade tomato sauce
2            1          Salsa          Spicy Salse
3            2          Bruschetta     Onion and Tomato Topping!
```

#### 'RecipeIngredients' Table

*NOTE: each recipe can only have a maximum of 5 ingredients, this will be limited during creation of recipe (during insert)*

```
recipeIngredientID     recipeID     ingredientID     amount
1                      1            1                3
2                      2            1                2
3                      2            2                1
4                      3            1                2
4                      3            2                1
4                      3            3                2
```

## What I need

I want to be able to do a query to list all recipes and would give me the following data per row.

- RecipeID
- RecipeName
- RecipeDescription
- UserID
- UserName
- Ingredient1
- Ingredient1Amount
- Ingredient2
- Ingredient2Amount
- Ingredient3
- Ingredient3Amount
- Ingredient4
- Ingredient4Amount
- Ingredient5
- Ingredient5Amount
- NOTE: Only goes up to Ingredient5 because recipes can only have at max 5 ingredients

#### Sample of what I'm looking for

- (1, 'Tomato Sauce', 'My homemade tomato sauce', 1, 'John', 'Tomatoes', '3', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
- (1, 'Salsa', 'Spicy salsa', 1, 'John', 'Tomatoes', 2, 'Onions', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
- (1, 'Bruschetta Topping', 'Onion and Tomato Topping', 2, 'Jane', 'Tomatoes', 2, 'Onions', 1, 'Red Pepper', 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

#### Sample of what I'm looking for in table format

```
RecipeID    RecipeName    RecipeDescription           UserID    UserName    Ingredient1    Ingredient1Image    Ingredient1Amount    Ingredient2    IIngredient1Image    Ingredient2Amount    Ingredient3    Ingredient1Image    Ingredient3Amount    Ingredient4    Ingredient1Image    Ingredient4Amount    Ingredient5    Ingredient1Image    Ingredient5Amount
1           Tomato Sauce  My homemade tomato sauce    1         John        Tomatoes       tomato.png          3                    NULL           NULL                 NULL                 NULL           NULL                NULL                 NULL           NULL                NULL                 NULL           NULL                NULL
2           Salsa         Spicy salsa                 1         John        Tomatoes       tomato.png          2                    Onions         onion.png            1                    NULL           NULL                NULL                 NULL           NULL                NULL                 NULL           NULL                NULL
3           Bruschetta    Onion and Tomato Topping    2         Jane        Tomatoes       tomato.png          2                    Onions         onion.png            1                    Red Pepper     redPepper.png       2                    NULL           NULL                NULL                 NULL           NULL                NULL
```

## Help

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked into 'MAX(CASE ...' statements (as shown here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql) but doesn't seem to work on this situation since the ingredients list will end up being very large (where as the subjects in the example are a pretty small set).

**EDIT**
What is the best practice for this? I see that it would be simpler to pull the recipes then do a nested loop to pull ingredients, but that seems intensive especially if the user count gets too large. I've also considered de-normalizing the table, but I will need the data normalized for future analytics/statistics, for potential questions like: how many recipes use tomatoes or something along those lines.

## TL;DR

I have normalized tables that I want to get into a single row to display to the user, and the 'MAX(CASE...' solution does not work for me since the dataset will be very large

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Comment: Question:- Why are u applying max condition of 5 ingredients on this query when u can apply it at the time of inserting the ingredient into the recipe table. It will make this query easier.

Comment: Hi, @adarshhota: that is the problem, can't seem to come up with a code  (added a link to what I was thinking of initially) for it. I've looked into the "max(case ..." statements for mimicing pivoting by doesn't seem practical for this situation since the 'cases' will be a very large set.

Comment: Hi @Purushottamzende: i'll edit, may have not worded it correctly, but as you mentioned, the limit is during insert not during the pull/query to display results.

Comment: @TLogan , i think its better to have simple left join for ingredients with their respective recepies, so u will get 5 rows with different ingredient in eac row but u r recipes and user details will be repeated, but u can handle them at the time of displaying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using multiple `LEFT JOIN`s. Joining the user is fairly simple. Joining the ingredients is a little more complex, as you have to join the `RecipeIngredients` table first and then use that id to join the ingredient. (note this only has the first 2 ingredients, the next/last 3 can be done the same way)

```
SELECT 
    r.recipeID, r.recipeName, r.description, 
    u.userID, u.userName,
    I1.ingredientName as Ingredient1, I1.ingredientImage as Ingredient1Image, rI1.amount as Ingredient1Amount,
    I2.ingredientName as Ingredient2, I2.ingredientImage as Ingredient2Image, rI2.amount as Ingredient2Amount
FROM
    Recipes r
LEFT JOIN 
    Users u 
ON 
    u.userID = r.userID

/*First Ingredient*/
LEFT JOIN 
    RecipeIngredients rI1 
ON 
    rI1.recipeIngredientID = (
      SELECT 
          rIa.recipeIngredientID 
      FROM RecipeIngredients rIa 
      WHERE rIa.recipeID = r.recipeID ORDER BY rIa.recipeIngredientID LIMIT 0,1 )
LEFT JOIN 
    Ingredients I1 
ON 
    I1.ingredientID = rI1.ingredientID

/*Second Ingredient*/
LEFT JOIN 
    RecipeIngredients rI2 
ON 
    rI2.recipeIngredientID = (
      SELECT 
          rIb.recipeIngredientID 
      FROM RecipeIngredients rIb 
      WHERE rIb.recipeID = r.recipeID ORDER BY rIb.recipeIngredientID LIMIT 1,1 )
LEFT JOIN 
    Ingredients I2 
ON 
    I2.ingredientID = rI2.ingredientID
```

Here is a working sqlFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3215e1/6

Comment: Anyway to make this dynamic? or would making it dynamic via php be sufficient? Would this be the best way of going about it for large user base (in terms of speed/efficiency)?

Comment: also, could you explain what is happening here: rIa.recipeIngredientID LIMIT 0,1 and rIb.recipeIngredientID LIMIT 1,1? and how that will work for the next few

Comment: Yes, you could use php to dynamically build your query. The `ORDER BY recipeIngredientID LIMIT 1,1` is to order the rows by the id, and then select only 1 row - `LIMIT 0,1` for ingredient 1, `LIMIT 1,1` for ingredient 2, `LIMIT 2,1` for ingredient 3, `LIMIT 3,1` for ingredient 4, and `LIMIT 4,1` for ingredient 5